# How to derive this inequality for the integral of $exp(x)^2$?

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, integral-inequality

Im looking at the solution of some exercise problem. It uses the following inequality

$$\frac{1}{\sigma} \int_0^{\theta-\theta_0} \left(\exp(x/\sigma) \cdot A - \frac{1}{2\sigma}\right)^2 \,dx \leq \left(A - \frac{1}{2\sigma}\right)^2 \left(\exp(\frac{\theta-\theta_0}{\sigma}) - 1\right)$$

I struggle to derive this inequality. We have $\sigma > 0, \theta - \theta_0 > 0$. What is happening here? How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look right. Set $\sigma=A=1$ and to make it simpler rename $t=\theta-\theta_{0}$.

So the inequality becomes
$$
\int_{0}^{t}\bigg(e^x-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{2} dx\leq \frac{1}{4}(e^{t}-1)
$$

The function in the integral is $e^{2x}-e^{x}+\frac{1}{4}$ so an antiderivate is $\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}-e^{x}+\frac{1}{4}x$. Then FTC makes the previous inequality into
$$
\frac{1}{2}e^{2t}-e^{t}+\frac{1}{4}t +\frac{1}{2}\leq \frac{1}{4}(e^{t}-1)
$$

Multiply through by $4$ to make it nicer, and move some things around:
$$
2e^{2t}+t+3\leq 5e^{t}
$$

But this false for any $t>0$ (at least).